# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

In learning android I'm making an ICMP ping program.  I added an AsyncTask thread to prevent "networking in main" and now my programming is throwing this run time exception (the one in the title).  I'm new to android; if you guys could help me out that would be really great.  Here the problematic logcat errors:

```
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.icmpping.Joe/com.icmpping.Joe.PingAppActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.icmpping.Joe.PingAppActivity.<init>(PingAppActivity.java:15)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
05-30 13:52:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  ... 11 more
```

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with AsyncTask.  The ICMP_Ping.ping method is from another class which returns a String object and takes a String parameter.  It uses java.net.InetAddress and System.currentTimeMillis().  Anyway, here is my main class:

////

```
package com.icmpping.Joe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PingAppActivity extends Activity {

private TextView console = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXT_STATUS_ID);

private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.d("pingactivity", "Hey LOGCAT2");

        EditText urlbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url_edittext);
        String url = urlbox.getText().toString();

        Log.d("pingactivity", "Hey LOGCAT3");
        new AsyncPing().execute(url);


        Log.d("pingactivity", "Hey LOGCAT4");
    }
};


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.d("pingactivity", "Hey LOGCAT0");

    Button pingbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ping_button);

    pingbutton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    Log.d("pingactivity", "Hey LOGCAT1");

}


private class AsyncPing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        return ICMP_Ping.ping(url[0]);
    }

    //protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {}

    protected void onPostExecute(String pingresult) {
        console.append(pingresult);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line   `TextView console = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextid);`

put after `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

```
    TextView console;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.d("pingactivity", "Hey LOGCAT0");

        Button pingbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ping_button);
        console = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextid);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that works!  I have a basic Java question though.  How can TextView console be in the class body and not have a visibility modifier.  Shouldn't it be private TextView console;?

Comment: `private` field access only in declared class ...other class cant access it